# Configuring xterm without access to xrdb on Red Hat 6.10

Tags: rhel, configuration, colors, xterm, x-resources

To give some context, I try to configure an environment in which I just arrived. The targeted development environment is confined on a remote Red Hat 6.10 system, only accessible through putty on a windows 8 box, with no permission to install anything on any of this system beyond what's possible as unprivileged user.

So I'm trying to have a terminal more shiny than the default putty terminal. As a first approach, I looked at putty coloration possibilities. I failed to apply a [reg file to set Putty color scheme as suggested by darekkay](https://darekkay.com/blog/my-putty-color-scheme/), as I have no idea how to get the `SESSION_NAME` that should be set (although I tried with my username without much results). However I successfully duplicated the scheme manually, so it's already better on this side.

Next I thought I might have more options with an [u]xterm, and especially I hoped it would bring me a more portable solution with a plain text configuration file. So I started to looking at the documentation, and started feeling the `~/.Xresources`configuration file. But launching `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` resulted in a `command not found`. I scanned through the xterm manual, hopping to find a way to provide directly a configuration file, but found nothing. So I’m left with no clue on how I might configure the xterm on this confined RHEL6.10 box.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `~/.Xresourses` is a new thing, and using `~/.Xdefaults` instead solved the issue.

Source: 
https://superuser.com/questions/243914/xresources-or-xdefaults